# Select By Attribute: If-Then VB Statement

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, select-by-attribute, vbscript, if-statement

I am attempting to write an If-Then Statement where if all the UtilityBillingMerge101719.() are true then return all of the results that are true that have an account number.

This currently works, but am struggling to get it into an if-then format.

[image: ct By Attricbute]

Comment: Simply invert the selection?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by an if-then statement. And the screen shots you show are not VB Script. They are SQL. The query builder is sort of like an if-then statement, in the sense that it selects everything that matches the conditions you give. But your query is not going to do what you want. OR and AND have the same weight, so the query will return true if any of the first three conditions are true, or if the last two are both true.

Comment: You would need to add parentheses to group all the ORs together so that the AND would apply to all of them. But then you'd get records that do have an account number, but either water or sewer is blank/null. Which doesn't sound like what you want.